# Объект View с анимацией в отображении

Tags: анимация, android, java, разметка

Здавствуйте. Имеется ли такая возможность - реализовать в приложении под Android класс, наследующий View с элементами анимации в отображении? Если есть, то какими средствами это делается? Стандартные View-ы можно "оживить" в xml-файле разметки либо все делается исключительно кодом? Скажем, необходимо сделать растягивающийся из центра до краёв экрана список, кнопку или текстовое поле. По инициализации происходит анимация такого рода, после чего компонент ожидает действий со стороны пользователя. Заранее, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так. Определить анимацию масштабирования в XML, а затем применить ее в Java.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.75" 
    android:toXScale="1.25"
    android:fromYScale="0.75" 
    android:toYScale="1.25" 
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="50%" 
    android:startOffset="0" 
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillBefore="true" />
```

и

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animation.scaling);

v.startAnimation(a);
```

где v - это то View, к которому применяется анимация. Также можно анимацию использовать и без XML

```
ScaleAnimation a = new ScaleAnimation((float)0.75, (float)1.25, (float)0.75, (float)1.25, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробуем это в коде.